# Sublime codeintel autocomplete does not work sometimes

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublimecodeintel

I have an issue when working in JS. If I have a string which i `split` into an array. For some reason when I start typing my variable followed by the first few letters of splice than there is no autocomplete for `splice` only split is displayed. See image bellow:

[image]

If I declare an array which I want to `splice` the `splice` autocomplete function is displayed. See image bellow:

[image]

Is there no way to always have the `splice` function visible in the autocomplete?

Comment: That looks like the package doesn't do the sort of dynamic flow analysis of code required to know that even though the initial value of `userInput` was a string (for which you can `split`) it is now an array that has a `splice()` attribute. Does the settings include anything that seems like it would turn something like that on?

Comment: Does not look like its supported. I would prefer it to not even analyse what type the variable is. I wish it would just show all functions possible.